# Debug Codeception with Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, codeception

I am writing a test application for an API using Codeception and I haven't manage to make the xdebug work for it in Netbeans. I have to mention I am using xampp on windows.

What I did is to set a new run configuration with Run As set to Script, PHP Interpreter set to C:\xampp\php\php.exe, Index file set to vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept and Arguments to run.

The thing is that the debug is starting and in the debug window it shows the following lines, but then it freezes there:

```
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "C:\xampp\htdocs\apitester\vendor\codeception\codeception   \codecept" "run"
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v1.8.5
Powered by PHPUnit 3.7.37 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Cli Tests (47)   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to bootstrap project (BootstrapCest.bootstrapProject)
```

In a normal command promt, the command "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "C:\xampp\htdocs\apitester\vendor\codeception\codeception   \codecept" "run" works

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has this problem: I forgot to set the working directory

Comment: What did you set it to?